# Ida python find function address that using string

Tags: ida, idapython

I have string at address `0xaaaa` that I want to know the address of function that use this string

```
import idautils
len(list(idautils.XrefsTo(0xaaaa,1)))
```

return 0

Why is that ? When I tried this code with function address that work.

So how can I find the **address of function** that using string that located at `0xaaaa` address?

Answer (score 2):

From `idautils` reference:

```
Parameters:
    ea - Reference address
    flags - one of ida_xref.XREF_ALL (default), ida_xref.XREF_FAR, ida_xref.XREF_DATA
```

Strings are usually (precisely always, unless some crazy binary editing comes into play) stored in the data segment, so you can try the data segment flag (`ida_xref.XREF_DATA`).